# How to force a shut down instead of reboot?

Tags: windows-server-2008, shutdown, reboot

Some processes like installation of drivers or some updates force the PC to reboot.

Is it possible, in Windows Vista/2008, to set an option so that the PC will automatically shut down instead of reboot every time when the reboot request is made by those processes?

Comment: When a reboot request is made by an application/process, simply decline it and shutdown the PC yourself. Are you looking for something else? Please clarify.

Comment: @Thomas, I apologize that my question was unclear. I edited it to explain what do I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no option you can set to do it automatically every time as you requested...that cannot be done because that is programmatic for each application or update package, but as the others said, you can just manually shut down.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  When a program requests a reboot you can initiate shutdown instead.  Any changes that would have been made on reboot will occur the next time the system boots.